# Careers button needs a space

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

The "Extend" and "User Permissions" buttons need an `&nbsp;` between them.

[image]

Comment: -1 for not drawing a freehand arrow.

Comment: That is freehand ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]