# Adding a project on careers, strange link

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, hyperlinks

Going to add a "project" to my careers profile yields a strange "return to my profile" hyperlink as shown:

[image]

PS: [This time I ensured it was really free hand.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250119/careers-button-needs-a-space) I should get some sort of award for making careers a much better app. **bows**

Comment: We are going to look into this. In the meantime, and as a small reward, here is a [picture of a kitten](http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png)

Comment: I hate cats!!!!!!!

Comment: What about a [baby duck](http://goo.gl/brgJjP)?

Comment: Much much better.

Comment: [Red Panda](http://seveninchesofyourtime.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Yawning-Red-Panda.jpg)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed! Thanks for the report :)

The Razor view was saved without a UTF-8 BOM which made MVC do odd things when rendering it.